# SOLR \ Boost phrases docs

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, lucene, proximity

Let's say I wanna search docs with Term1 Term2 Term3
How can I boost those docs that these terms are closer? 
only proximity is to tight for me as I want to get docs with only term1 and term2 for example...

I know there is SOLR param that take all the query and wrap it in some phrase boost?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bool Query which can contain a combination of queries which may include exact match, partial match or proximity match. For different types of queries take a look at [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html).

Also, please go through [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/proximity-matching.html). This is a very good article about Proximity matching in ES.

Thanks